# how to make sql developer display diacritic character correctly instead of displaying squares?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am unable to see the diacritic characters (with accents) in my oracle SQL Developer. I have tried with all the Font option. Is any way I can add the "Arial Unicode MS" font in my oracle SQLDeveloper and see the character instead of the square box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Developer is based on pure Java and JDBC there is the a possibility that the data itself were stored wrong - this could happen when you used not proper client NLS_LANG value and/or wrong codepage (Windows) or LANG (Linux / Unix). Since Data allready in DB and fetch with SQL Developer returns crap, this is by 95% a NLS issue.
Please let us know Database Charachterset and NLS_LANG and Codepage (chcp) settings of  client. You can perform

```
Select <Colname>, dump(<colname>) "Dump" from <table>;
```

To return a column and dump in Sqlplus.
Provide

- NLS_LANG of client
- Client codepage (Windows) or LANG (Linux)
- Database Charachterset
- the value from select,
- the expected value and
- value from SQL Developer performing the same select as shown above

and we will see